# error parsing hostname.yml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 21: did not find expected key

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I am trying to deploy a sample application on the Kubernetes cluster but I am facing the error:

> error parsing hostname.yml: error converting YAML to JSON: YAML: line 21: did not find expected key

Below is my hostaname.yml file

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
 name: hostname-v1 
 spec:
   replicas: 1
   selector:
   matchLabels:
  app: hostname
  strategy:
  rollingUpdate:
   maxSurge: 1
    maxUnavailable: 1
   type: RollingUpdate
   template:
    metadata:
    labels:
     app: hostname
      version: v1
       spec:
       containers:
         - image: akslearning.azurecr.io/hostname:v1
          imagePullPolicy: Always
         name: hostname
        resources: {}
       restartPolicy: Always
       apiVersion: v1
      kind: Service
     metadata:
      labels:
     app: hostname
    name: hostname
     spec:
         ports:
          - port: 80
           protocol: TCP
        targetPort: 80
        selector:
       app: hostname
     sessionAffinity: None
          type: LoadBalancer
```

Kindly suggest what to do

Comment: Please somehow (e.g. in the yaml code) mark the place where the key-error ocures (line 21) so we don't have to eye-parse your configuration and count lines.

Comment: Also this seems to be a formatting error, please try to validate that your yaml is valid before posting it... you have indentations mixed up. You use 1 and 2 spaces interchangingly

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few issues with formating. As first, if you are using more than 1 resource (`Deployment` and `Service`) you must separate them using `---`. Second thing, is that YAML format is strict, you cannot use `TABs`, only whitesigns using `spacebar` to use correct `indent`.

Please find, corrected YAMLs below:

```
cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hostname-v1 
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 1  
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hostname
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
       app: hostname  
       version: v1
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: hostname 
        resources: {}
      restartPolicy: Always
---       
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: hostname
  name: hostname
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: hostname
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  sessionAffinity: None
EOF
deployment.apps/hostname-v1 created
service/hostname created
```

However, I would also add `.metadata.labels` in your `Deployemnt` YAML as mentioned in [Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#creating-a-deployment)

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hostname-v1 
  labels:                #This line
    app: hostname        #And this line
spec:
...
```

If you will check this YAML in online `YAML to JSON converter`, like [codebeautify](https://codebeautify.org/yaml-to-json-xml-csv), it works perfectly.

Comment: @Nishar sheik please accept this answer if was helpful